# Newly added column is not visible

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I am using xampp on localhost. I created a table and then altered it, adding one more column after some time. The newly added column is not visible when I browse the table data, but it is  when I see the table structure. Why can't I see it in the table data?

I am using the portable package of xampp. Also, queries regarding to that column are running fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review your answer: it was quite hard to read. Please make them easier to read, using the proper formatting and grammar.

Comment: hows that possible? Can you post some screenshots? Also note that if your table is empty, you cant browse the table data using phpmyadmin

Answer (score 3):

I got a way for that:

- Export the table that is not showing a particular column on browsing
- Drop the table
- Import it

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I went to the "Operations" tab and copied the table to another database, and then I could drop the original table and copy back, or just switch the code. I have my database connections all set with one variable, so changing the code is really easy for me personally. Hope it helps! (Posting this again, incase anybody else is having this problem, as it really was a nuisance for me.)