# Newly added column not visible in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, alter-table

Firstly, this question has kind of been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030915/newly-added-column-is-not-visible).

The problem is that after creating a new column by using `ALTER TABLE`, a new column does get created, but *sometimes* it isn't shown in the structure tab. When it occurs, using `SELECT * FROM <tablename>` does not display that column but `SELECT <columnname> FROM <tablename>` does. All queries on that column work perfectly.

Solution to this problem was rightly posted and it was simple -- to export that complete table, drop it and then import it again.

My question is why does such a thing happen? It's really a nuisance. It isn't a problem when working locally, I can always import/export/drop, but what I have a piece of code that continuously drops/creates new columns? Why does this happen and why does an import/drop/export do the trick? Is it a bug with phpMyAdmin?

PS: I am using phpMyAdmin with XAMPP v3.2.1 on localhost.

Comment: Does a browser refresh not work? I'm sure it has worked for me in the past. Maybe log out and log in again? What version of phpMyAdmin are you running?

Comment: Browser refresh/restart/clear-cache doesn't work. Nor does a logout/login. I'm using v4.1.1 of phpMyAdmin, recently updated.

Comment: Works for me on phpMyAdmin 4.0.8, latest FF, OSX/SL. Added a column on the `mysql5` console, clicked the "Structure" tab on the right table, column is present. What browser are you running?

Comment: I'm using latest Google Chrome on Win 8.1 (64-bit). I tried it in FF too. Hell, I was so desperate that I even tried it out on IE!

Comment: If you have already re-installed phpMyAdmin, then take a backup and add some debug statements into the PHP in this application. Perhaps it is caching something in some way. I suspect you have a rare case here - I don't ever recall experiencing this.

Comment: Ah! There's the catch! It doesn't happen every time. Happened twice with me. And it has happened with many people. I looked on Google, people solved it in weird ways, by dropping/importing or by copying into a new table etc, but I couldn't find the reason this happens. That's what I seek.

Comment: if its problem with phpMyAdmin then it will never disturb your dynamic add/edit/remove columns in your code, its something with phpMyadmin version.

Comment: Right, so it is intermittent. That's a pretty important point - I've added that to the question. Again, debugging: leave some debug code in, so when it happens again, you can see where the problem occurs. Also, see if there is a bug report on the project tracker.

Comment: I'll try the debug code. Do you happen to have a snippet? I haven't done anything like that before.

Comment: Which XAMPP version are you using, and on which platform?

Comment: @MarcDelisle I'm using XAMPP v3.2.1 on Windows 8.1 64-bit.

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983232/alter-tabled-using-php-query-column-name-doesnt-show-up-in-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like your bumping into this known issue: http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4187/

The update goes to cache and therefore teh select * would come from cache versus the select "explicit column" which would pull directly from the DB. I'd imagine the export > drop > re-import process clears the cache with the drop.

Looks like its fixed in 4.1.2